# Does Asus Xonar DS work in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, asus

Does it work in Ubuntu (14.04.03) I dont want to buy it and let it rot on the shelf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried the DS (only the DG which use another chipset) myself but I have no reason to believe that it shouldn't work. According to http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Asus the DS is supported since kernel 2.6.37.